# Mountain rescue and medical care in Georgia?

Tags: health, georgia-country, insurance, mountains, emergencies

How does using the mountain rescue and medical care services (in case of emergency) work in Georgia? Is buying insurance required for an EU citizen? If so, how and where can I buy such insurance?

I'm asking only about public insurance, that enables me to use medical and rescue services for free, and not for private insurance, that would pay only the sum stated in insurance contract and only if their own criteria would be fulfilled...

Comment: From my experience in Georgia no such thing would be "required" and I didn't notice such insurance on offer in Georgia to travellers - but I also wasn't up in the mountains. Did you consider travel insurance though? It will cover you no matter what though you may have to specify any high risk activities when you buy the policy.

Comment: Usually, high risk activities are not covered by normal health care insurances. Anything that requires mountain resque is usually considered a high risk activity. So, if you want mountain rescue covered, you could probably need a specialised insurance.

Comment: but if you have real (public) health insurance, you're healed for free no matter why you've hurt yourself, so I was asking about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EHIC card, that offers state-provided health care abroad is applicable only to Economic European Area, which is basically EU plus a couple countries. Georgia is not part of this set so you will not have any standard health care protection there (any form of health care at all actually).

But honestly, I am not sure mountain rescuing is included in any state-provided protection.

As @hippietrail wrote in his comment, you can rely on private insurance. Actually, you should check your liability insurance contract or ask them if they cover that case.

Otherwise there are some private travel insurances that are around 50 euros a month, for this matter (like World Nomads, AVI internayional, ...)

Reference : http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=559